# How to get a relative path for CMake unit tests?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, catch2

I have a project built with CMake that uses Catch2 for unit tests. Some of the unit tests exercise code that loads data from a file like this:

```
std::string resource_dir = "TEST_CWD/resources/";
std::ifstream infile{resource_dir + "datafile.txt"}
```

The question is how to properly get the value of `TEST_CWD`.

The directory structure is simple (and not set in stone):

```
my_project/
    test/
        resources/datafile.txt
        loader_test.cpp
```

Leaving `TEST_CWD` blank sometimes works, but breaks when running tests through an IDE. Setting an environment variable with the absolute path also works, but will break on others' machines. Similarly forcing all users to manually set environment variables is user unfriendly.

What is a good way to specify relative file paths in CMake projects?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know about relative paths, but you can use `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` to get the path to the top-level directory of your project-- where the main CMakeLists.txt file is.

From the [CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html) for `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`:

> The path to the top level of the source tree.
>
> This is the full path to the top level of the current CMake source tree. For an in-source build, this would be the same as CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.

Then you can just base all your paths off of this. For example, in a CMake script, you could write `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/resources/datafile.txt`.

**Edit:**

If you need access to this value in your C++ code itself, you could use the `configure_file` command. For example you could create a file called something like `Config.h.in`...

```
// Config.h.in

#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#define SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"

#endif
```

... and then in your CMakeLists.txt file,

```
configure_file(Config.h.in ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Config.h)

include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

Then you could include `Config.h` like a normal header, and be on your way!

**Single variable shortcut**

Just use a preprocessor macro. In the `CMakeLists.txt` in `test/`:

```
target_compile_definitions(target_name PUBLIC TEST_RESOURCE_DIR="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources/")
```

in C++:

```
std::string resource_dir = TEST_RESOURCE_DIR;
```

Comment: Probably for only one variable it is simpler just to pass it to preprocessor directly through `-D`

Comment: I used `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` instead because it appears to be even safer, particularly if someone adds my project to theirs using `add_directory`. I hope you don't mind I edited your answer with the approach I actually followed, using a preprocessor directive because I have nothing else to configure.

Comment: i found "Single variable shortcut" to be the easiest solution here

Comment: If you need it in your C++ ode, using `-DSOURCE_PATH=...` would be easier, I think (except for escaping, you need to make sure the path doesn't break your command line.)

Comment: Thanks BeeGee.  Until I read your comment I thought I had to do all of that, and didn't realize I could just do from the Shortcut on